# Swift Adding Subview with UITableView Press

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm very new to swift so sorry if this is  a basic question or I'm doing something terribly wrong. I've been having some issues trying to add a subview when touching a row on a tableview and have been working off of this page: http://myxcode.net/2015/11/07/adding-a-subview-using-a-xib-and-storyboard/

Here's the relevant code I have so far (I removed some of the tableview logic because that works fine):

Subview Class

```
class ConfirmTeamView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var teamListTableView2: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmButton2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cancelButton2: UIButton!


var playerList: [Player]?
var view: UIView!

init(pList: [Player]) {

    self.playerList = pList
    super.init(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 385, 339))

    setup()

    teamListTableView2.delegate = self
    teamListTableView2.dataSource = self

    let playerListTableCellNib = UINib(nibName: "PlayerListTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    teamListTableView2.registerNib(playerListTableCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PlayerListTableViewCell")

}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.playerList = nil
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   setup()
}

func setup() {

    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight,UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth]
    addSubview(view)

}

func loadViewFromNib () -> UIView
{
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ConfirmTeamView", bundle: bundle)

    //this line I think is causing a stack overflow, any idea why?
    let thisview = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView 


    return thisview
}
```

}

and then in my viewController (I again removed some tableview methods for ease of reading):

```
class ChooseExistingTeamViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var TeamListTableView: UITableView!

var existingTeamsArray = [Team]()
var confirmTeamUI : ConfirmTeamView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    TeamListTableView.delegate = self
    TeamListTableView.dataSource = self

    let testPlayer1 = Player(name: "John", number: 24)
    let testPlayer2 = Player(name: "Smith", number: 50)
    let testTeam = Team(name: "myTeam", players: [testPlayer1, testPlayer2])

    existingTeamsList = [testTeam]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // This is where I load the subview

    TeamListTableView.userInteractionEnabled = false

    let selectedTeam = existingTeamsList[indexPath.row]
    let confirmTeamUI = ConfirmTeamView(pList: selectedTeam.players)

    confirmTeamUI.cancelButton2.addTarget(self, action: "cancelPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let viewWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let xWidth = viewWidth - 40
    let yHeight = 200
    confirmTeamUI.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: Int(xWidth), height: yHeight)

    self.view.addSubview(confirmTeamUI)
}

func cancelPressed(sender: UIButton) {

  //  self.confirmTeamUI.view.removeFromSuperview() [This line throws an exception for unwrapping an optional value]

    if self.confirmTeamUI != nil { self.confirmTeamUI.removeFromSuperview() }
    else { print("Confirm Team is nil") }
    // pressing the cancel button runs the else case
}
```

Any advice would be very appreciated and please let me know if you need more!

Comment: I have not read your entire code but why don't you keep the view in your hierarchy and on selection of cell, just unhide it and hide it on deselection?

Comment: This code looks like you are trying to dynamically create a new view with a tableView inside an existing row of a tableView (when clicked).  Is that what you are trying to do?  If not, maybe be more specific about what you are trying to do (i.e. display an image in a tableViewCell when the cell is clicked)

Comment: @RajeevBhatia I can try that too! Still trying to figure out what I can and cant do.

Comment: @DJohnson sorry about the lack of detail, I'll add them to the original post. I am trying to dynamically create a new subview (essentially a popup) whose data populates based on which row in the tableview was selected.